# min-inline-size not works as expected like min-width in media queries

Tags: html, css

I have media query here:

```
@media screen and (min-inline-size: 900px) {
    ...
}
```

but it's not working however with `min-width` it works well. Although when using `min-inline-size` as a property in body of selector (not as query in media rule) it works. **Isn't it supported in query types yet?**

Comment: I'm noting that `min-inline-size` is not on the list of media features: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Instead of `min-inline-size` you can use `min-height`, If you are trying to apply media query depending on the height of the device.

Comment: @AnjaliRawat Thank you for answer. Yes absolutely I can but it is better I think to use `min-inline-size` for same reason it exists for different `writing-mode`-s

Comment: [Container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container#descriptors) support the inline size. If you want to simulate the behaviour, you can define a root container and query to it with `inline-size > 900px`.

Answer (score 1):

`min-inline-size` is not yet supported in media queries, as per Google's Web.dev site.

[https://web.dev/learn/design/macro-layouts/#:~:text=While%20it%20would%20make%20more%20sense%20to%20specify%20min%2Dinline%2Dsize%20instead%20of%20min%2Dwidth%2C%20logical%20properties%20don%27t%20work%20in%20media%20queries%20yet](https://web.dev/learn/design/macro-layouts/#:%7E:text=While%20it%20would%20make%20more%20sense%20to%20specify%20min%2Dinline%2Dsize%20instead%20of%20min%2Dwidth%2C%20logical%20properties%20don%27t%20work%20in%20media%20queries%20yet).